# Get several values from option to assign to Request.Form[]

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, umbraco, html-select

I need to store both the name and the id of the option the user chooses in my SQL Database. Right now I am only storing the Id, by setting the value of the option to the current Id in the iteration.

```
@foreach (var item in selection)
{
     if (item.Id.ToString() == contentId)
     {
         //dont mind this, just for displaying purposes         
     }
     else
     {
        <option value="@item.Id" @(Request.Form["førstePrio"] != null && Request.Form["førstePrio"].ToString().Equals(item.Name.ToString()) ? " selected" : "")>@item.Name</option>
     }
 }
```

How can I store the @item.Name value as well in a separate Request.Form?

Edit:

```
@{
   var selection = Model.Content.Site().FirstChild("Sprog").FirstChild("sommerhuse").Children()
   .Where(x => x.IsVisible());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At the moment, the item.id is the value of the selection.

What you'd actually want to receive on the surface controller at this point would be the item / model itself

There's an example of such a controller here;

https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Templating/Mvc/forms#creating-the-surfacecontroller-action

So you would want to post the whole object to this controller. From there you would be able to get whatever properties you needed from the model, in order to save them to the DB.

It would be something like

```
<option value="@item" @(Request.Form["førstePrio"] != null && Request.Form["førstePrio"].ToString().Equals(item.Name.ToString()) ? " selected" : "")>@item.Name</option>
```

Comment: I don't have a surface controller associated with the view. I am retrieving all my other form values and submitting them to the DB in the view using System.Data.SqlClient. This works well for all the other form inputs. I've added the model for my select in my original post.